# Ansible - How to apply a different ssh config to a specific host?

Tags: ansible

Below is the play for applying the ssh config to a specific host:

```yaml
- name: Add a host in the configuration
  community.general.ssh_config:
    ssh_config_file: "{{ ssh_config_path }}"
    host: "example.com"
    state: present
```

We have two variants of ssh config: `ssh_config1` & `ssh_config2`

- `ssh_config1` needs to be applied on group(`group1`) of hosts
- `ssh_config2` needs to be applied on a specific single host `host1.abc.com`(not in `group1`)

How should the play perform this functionality?

Requirement is to apply a specific

Comment: The hosts line is probably what you want. See here for an example https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html

Answer (score 2):

Taking for granted that:

- this playbook will target any hosts in your inventory
- you have a valid inventory already containing `group1`, the specific host `host1.abc.com` and any other
- you want to skip that config task for any host not having `ssh_config_path` configured.
- you have removed any definition of the `ssh_config_path` variable from any other place in your environment

In `group_vars/group1.yml`

```yaml
---
ssh_config_path: /path/to/ssh_config1
```

In `host_vars/host1.abc.com.yml`

```yaml
---
ssh_config_path: /path/to/ssh_config2
```

Then the following (untested) playbook should meet your requirement

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Add a host in the configuration
      community.general.ssh_config:
        ssh_config_file: "{{ ssh_config_path }}"
        host: "example.com"
        state: present
      when: ssh_config_path is defined
```

Alternatively, if you want to play the above only on the given hosts, with the exact same configuration and inner task, you can simply replace the `host:` stanza above with:

```yaml
  hosts: group1:host1.abc.com
```

Comment: Why are we mentioning `host: "example.com"`?